# multiple threads invoking using qthread

Tags: qt, qthread

Its my basic question i want to ask the experts regarding my design before i start coding

I have to invoke five different threads

> 3 of UDP send/recv with individual structure 
>   2 of Multicast UDP with
>   individual structure  1 of Serial

Can i create a class for each qthread object or is there any other better way in qt to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details

This describes the two ways to create a function and have it managed by a thread, with the first way to be the preferred method.

Hope that helps.